# Show xrange x and x2 values in chart

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

How to show the min and max or x and x2 values in the chart and Need the partial fill to in value than %.

```
min = 0;
max = 150;
y=95; //points scored.

{
    showInLegend: false,
    pointWidth: 25,
    data: [{
      x: 0,
      x2: 150,
      y: 0,
      partialFill: 0.75
    }],
    dataLabels: {
      enabled: true
    }
  }
```

0 -------------------95points---------------150

Fiddle Example: https://jsfiddle.net/bv4uyazq/

Comment: Are you trying to show a min and max value if x1 x2 < min and max?

Comment: xrange doesn't support plotOptions; I want to display the start and end point i.e., 0 and 150.
Sorry for edit : min and max ==> x and x2

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly you can achieve it following these approaches:

1) render custom labels using SVGRenderer:

**Code:**

```
chart: {
  type: 'xrange',
  events: {
    render: function() {
      var chart = this,
        offsetTop = -8,
        offsetLetf = 5,
        x1,
        x2,
        y,
        label1,
        label2,
        label2BBox;

      if (chart.customLabels && chart.customLabels.length) {
        chart.customLabels.forEach(function(label) {
          label.destroy();
        });
      }

      chart.customLabels = [];

      chart.series[0].points.forEach(function(point) {

        x1 = point.plotX + chart.plotLeft + offsetLetf;
        x2 = x1 + point.shapeArgs.width - 2 * offsetLetf;
        y = point.plotY + chart.plotTop + point.shapeArgs.height / 2 + offsetTop;

        label1 = chart.renderer.text(chart.xAxis[0].dataMin, x1, y).css({
          fill: '#fff'
        }).add().toFront();

        label2 = chart.renderer.text(chart.xAxis[0].dataMax, x2, y).css({
          fill: '#fff'
        }).add().toFront();

        label2BBox = label2.getBBox();
        label2.translate(-label2BBox.width, 0);

        chart.customLabels.push(label1);
        chart.customLabels.push(label2);
      });
    }
  }
}
```

**Demo:**

- https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/twuv96ex/1/

2) set xAxis labels positions as `dataMin` and `dataMax` and translate it using `offset` property:

**Code:**

```
  xAxis: {
    type: 'linear',
    visible: true,
    offset: -110,
    tickPositioner: function() {
      return [this.dataMin, this.dataMax];
    }
  }
```

**Demo:**

- https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/m7s4pfo5/

**API reference:**

- https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGRenderer#text
- https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.DataLabelsOptionsObject#formatter
- https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.offset